# How to add map search functionality to gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have built an app using Rails 4 and the Gmaps4rails gem.  I have a map with markers (it works great).  I would like to add a search box and functionality to search the map.  So, the map would centre around the searched term (like a city) and then display any markets nearby. I can't find documentation on how to do this via Gmaps4rails.  Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Gmaps4rails is a google map wrapper it doesnt limit you in any way. How do you do your search, what are its results? The question is too broad

Answer (score 0):

### How to change default zoom for a map (Gmaps4rails) with one pin

You must add to the view of the page with the map a line to the series of "handler" lines. The code below is from an answer by [apneadiving](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350087/apneadiving) to a different question that helped me find my answer. The second part below sets the zoom level (`handler.getMap().setZoom(8);`).

```
handler.buildMap( {internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  // handler.map is the proxy object created by the gem, 
  // where you can add your custom methods,
  // like centerOn
  handler.map.centerOn([-34.397, 150.644]);

  // handler.getMap() is the google map object
  // you can also access it with handler.map.getServiceObject()
  handler.getMap().setZoom(8);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Joshua - your answer was extremely helpful.  I was able to make it work with your insight.  Cheers!